# WCF port routing

Tags: wcf, port

I have NAT which received incoming WCF requests and changes port number before it hands off to the host however, this is causing problem is there anyway to turn this off or fix?

ex)  wcf.service.com:80 -> NAT -> wcf.service.2522 !error

Thank you.

Comment: what error do you get? And how and where do you want to "turn it off" ??

Comment: What binding are you using Net.TCP/BasicHTTP/wsHTTP?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about the binding you are using we cant say much right now.

For starters, edit your config using the WCF Service Configuration Editor tool and turn on the diagnostics.  Namely the Tracing section

Then run your service and hit it a couple of times. This should produce a trace log file (*.svclog) which you can open in the WCF Trace Viewer tool.   Look for red exceptions and pay attention to any yellow warnings.

If you haven't spotted your problem by now, post some of that information here, and we all can help you a bit better ;)